# __init__ and the setting of class variables

Tags: python, variables, inheritance

Im having some trouble understanding Inheritance in classes and wondering why this bit of python code is not working, can anyone walk me through what is going wrong here?

```
## Animal is-a object 
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, sound):
        self.implimented = False
        self.name = name
        self.sound = sound

    def speak(self):
        if self.implimented == True:
            print "Sound: ", self.sound

    def animal_name(self):
        if self.implimented == True:
            print "Name: ", self.name



## Dog is-a Animal
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        self.implimented = True
        name = "Dog"
        sound = "Woof"

mark = Dog(Animal)

mark.animal_name()
mark.speak()
```

This is the output through the terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/nd/4r8kqczj19j1yk8n59f1pmp80000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/ex41-376235301.968.py", line 26, in <module>
    mark = Dog(Animal)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
logout
```

I was trying to get animal to check if an animal was implemented, and then if so, get the classes inheriting from animal to set the variables that Animals would then be able to manipulate.

Comment: Do note that your `if` statements are a little odd here. `if self.implimented == True:` can be simplified to `if self.implimented:`.

Comment: But isn't it previously set to false in the __init__?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To create an instance of a class you do

   ```
   mark = Dog()
   ```

   not `mark = Dog(Animal)`.
2. Don't do this `implimented` stuff. If you want a class that you can't instantiate (i.e. you have to subclass first), do

   ```
   import abc
   class Animal(object):
       __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

       def speak(self):
           ...
   ```

Comment: Why not do the implemented stuff? what would be a better way of having the code check to see the animal (class) exists? or like for example if one of the animals was a koala that didn't speak.

Comment: @lerugray you can't have it both ways: if you define an animal to be something that can speak, then a koala-that-can't-speak is not an animal.

Comment: You could of course set `self.sound = None` for those animals that don't speak, then check in your `speak` method whether sound is not None.

Answer (score 6):

katrielalex answered your question pretty well, but I'd also like to point out that your classes are somewhat poorly - if not incorrectly - coded. There seems to be few misunderstandings about the way you use classes.

First, I would recommend reading the Python docs to get the basic idea: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

To create a class, you simply do

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, sound): # class constructor
        self.name = name
        self.sound = sound
```

And now you can create name objects by calling `a1 = Animal("Leo The Lion", "Rawr")` or so.

To inherit a class, you do:

```
# Define superclass (Animal) already in the class definition
class Dog(Animal):

    # Subclasses can take additional parameters, such as age
    def __init__(self, age):

        # Use super class' (Animal's) __init__ method to initialize name and sound
        # You don't define them separately in the Dog section
        super(Dog, self).__init__("Dog", "Woof")

        # Normally define attributes that don't belong to super class
        self.age = age
```

And now you can create a simple `Dog` object by saying `d1 = Dog(18)` and you don't need to use `d1 = Dog(Animal)`, you already told the class that it's superclass is `Animal` at the first line `class Dog(Animal):`

Comment: Thanks this is a huge help, I'm teaching myself using LPTHW and recently Zed got rid of the comments section, so this helps tremendously, thank you!

Comment: @lerugray I've never been sure whether LPTHW is meant to be a parody or not. I definitely don't think it's a way to learn Python. I'd recommend [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/).

Comment: @Mahi But lets say I wanted to create a method to print the animal's age, would I define that as a function in the parent class and in the parent classes __init__ method as another argument?

Comment: If you wanted every last one of your animals to have an age, you would define both `age` and `printAge` in the parent class, `Animal`. If you wanted SOME of the animals to have an age, you would inherit `AgedAnimal` from `Animal`, which would implement `age` and `printAge`, and then inherit `Dog` from `AgedAnimal`. If only `Dog` has age, you code the `age` and `printAge` into `Dog`, and keep `Animal` as it is.

Comment: @Mahi +1, Your advice has been excellent, but it's worth noting that Python supports multiple inheritance, so rather than 'AgedAnimal', I would simple do 'Aged' and 'Animal' and subclass from both, in that particular case.

Comment: @Mahi last question lets say we want all animals to have age, would you define that in the __init__ function? or set a self.age = age inside the class? thank you for bearing with me

Comment: @Lattyware Supporting multiple inheritance doesn't mean there's any reason to use it. Most coders would call it a bad feature in any language. If you ever go to a big company, you are not allowed to, and you simply can't use multiple inheritance. Instead your `Animal` would already inherit from `Aged`.

Comment: @lerugray You would init `age` in the `Animal.__init__()` -method, yes. If there are two or more classes with common attributes (for example `age`), you code the common attribute into their Base class.

Comment: @Mahi I was taking your example of AgedAnimal being needed as only some animals would have an age. In that case, multiple inheritance makes sense. Some Java programmers might be afraid of MI, coming from the rigidly structured world of Java, that doesn't make it a bad feature.

Comment: @Lattyware Multiple inheritance might be designed for that exact purpose, but no, it does not make sense. To begin with, I'm a C++ programmer, not a Java programmer, what is wrong with everyone acting like they'd know something about the other person, or like if everyone was a Java coder? Second, there's a reason most programming languages don't support multiple inheritance: It's a mess, bad way of coding and against every possible rule in a good code. As I mentioned, if you'll ever get to create a real large project, you can't use multiple inheritance, regardless of the language.

Comment: @Mahi I was using Java as an example of a very rigid language that didn't support MI - I wasn't suggesting you were a Java programmer. If you could give some actual reasons for MI being a bad thing, that'd be great - I'm happy to read links. I agree it can be used to bad effect, but I don't see it being a bad thing in general.

Comment: @Lattyware The main reason is, that it breaks all the rules of a smart design. If you need MI, your program is designed incorrectly. I am not going to explain it here, it would need 100 comments and 20 pictures. Just take a look at any large project (fe. Windows, Google Chrome, etc.) You'll notice that none of them actually uses MI even when C++ support MI. If you have to, you'll learn one day. But to give you some more reasons, take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem Of course Python has it's way to go around, but it's still bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since age in the given example is not part of the parent (or *base*) class, you have to implement the the function (which in a class is called *method*) in the class which inheritted (also known as *derived* class).

```
class Dog(Animal):

    # Subclasses can take additional parameters, such as age
    def __init__(self, age):
        ... # Implementation can be found in reaction before this one

    def give_age( self ):
        print self.age
```

Comment: What exactly did this add to my answer? You don't **have to** implement a single method which you don't need. This answer is actually not true, and it might only distract newcomers.

Comment: @Mahi: at the time I gave my answer, I assumed that the OP wanted to implement age in the derived class since that was part of your example, which I only used as base. And I assumed he wanted a method to access age from that question.
I only tried to help.